# How do I run a program with extremely long arguments from BAT file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Basically I need to run a program (it's a java program, if that can help) from a bat file that has extremely long arguments, it's about 9000 symbols. The problem is that it seems so it truncates command line to something around 8000 symbols. 
I don't mind using powershell instead if that can help.
Thanks in advance. (And no, there is no way to make arguments shorter)

Comment: On Windows, the maximum command-line length is 32767 characters. (The 8191-character limit is imposed by cmd.exe.) How big are your "symbols"? If they are several characters long on average, and you have 9000 symbols, you'll hit the Windows limit whatever command-line interpreter you use.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: In the Windows user interface, the _command-line_ is the line given to cmd.exe for its execution, and such a line have a limit of 8192 characters. If there are other longer "command-lines" that can _not_ be given to cmd.exe, then such an info is certainly useless...

Comment: @Aacini why are they useless? cmd.exe is not the only possible command line on Windows. You could write an application that passes a 32Kb command line to another application - no cmd.exe used here. Obviously not from a bat file. But if the OP said he's happy with Powershell too, then that implies he's happy not to use a bat file (since Powershell doesn't use bat files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Start-Process` from PowerShell:

```
$argument = "This will exceed the 8191 character limitation" * 200
Start-Process java.exe -ArgumentList "-jar","path\to.jar",$argument
```

Comment: Interesting! How do you use this method _from BAT file_ as specifically stated in the question?

Comment: You could use an intermediate file to hold the command line, the BAT file passes the file name to a Powershell script, and the Powershell script then puts the contents of that file on the command line.